# JS Warning: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, warnings

Why do I get the warning `"expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"`?

First example

```
( this._mouseStarted ? this._mouseDrag( event ) : this._mouseUp( event ) );
```

Second example

```
( this.direction === "down" ? i.item[ 0 ] : i.item[ 0 ].nextSibling ) );
```

Comment: your second example has a extra `)` at the end of the line

Comment: ternary operators are not the best thing to use as an if/else hence the warning

Answer (score 0):

The warning is just there so you don't accidentally forget the variable (the assignment's left-hand side) that you would normally assign that expression's value to
https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/505a2f774f0e7400020021ba